# How can I white list slack web-hooks domain in PCF ASG's?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm using a pivotal cloud foundry to host my application. I need to whitelist slack-webhooks URL IP in the Application Security Group(ASG's). For now, I have hardcoded 3 IPs.

```
 {
    "description": "Slack-ip-1",
    "destination": "13.226.19.152",
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "ports": "443"
  },
  {
    "description": "Slack-ip-2",
    "destination": "13.249.130.154",
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "ports": "443"
  },
  {
    "description": "Slack-ip-3",
    "destination": "13.227.32.151",
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "ports": "443"
  }
```

But Slack uses AWS and there is a high possibility that these IPs will change frequently. Instead of hardcoded ips can I whitelist domain like `hooks.slack.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Application security groups translate down to iptables rules and [using domain names instead of IP addresses there is not recommended (for security and performance reasons)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27987243/1585136).

I think your best bet would be to have a cron script that runs periodically (maybe daily) which runs `dig` or `host` and resolves `hooks.slack.com` to fetch the IP addresses. If those change, you could either send yourself an alert, probably through slack :), so you can be reminded to update your ASGs or you could perhaps automatically update your ASGs from the script. Depends on how fancy you want to get.

Hope that helps!

Comment: how about `0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255`?

Comment: You could go the route of unblock all, that's a good point. AWS publishes a list of all their IP space, I believe this is it -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html. You'd have to translate that into an ASG rule and then it wouldn't matter if Slack changed. That comes with the downside that your app can now talk to anything on AWS, which is quite a lot of stuff.

Comment: I don't work for Slack or AWS, so I can't give you a definitive answer, but what you're saying logically makes sense.